# What's Download and Upload Packet?

Tags: http, download, upload, packet

**Note:** My question remains un-answered.

After hours of reading I'm confused about download/upload speeds.

Let's suppose I sent an http request to fetch an image, all websites mention this as "Download" but why?

My computer is sending the request and getting a response back, so it's both uploading (sending packet) and downloading (getting packet). Thus it's not pure Download.

Plus, I read that internet provides prioterize download over upload but how? given a packet from A to B how can they decide if it's an upload or download?

From A's perspective it's Upload, but according to B it's Download...

Answer (score 0):

Where did you read about prioritizing download speed over upload? ISPs can only prioritize speed traffic by IP (to move traffic to another chanel out of shaper or to make this traffic use another shaper's rules) or by shaper set rules for UDP, Vo-Ip or traffic per VLAN/port. Web sites can optimize data for displaying content cached and compressed, for example. Or to use the uploading feature on other upstream servers.  But you, as a user, upload to the server RAW data (an uncompressed set of bytes). For managing speeds from an ISP, the ISP must monitor each packet from each user. And then it can limit speeds either by packet size (but it will work 50/50 'cos files are uploaded by a few requests) or by meta data from a packet. It is a massive load for all infrastructure. And accordingly, it is a very costly process for businesses.

Comment: Thanks, but can you answer my specific questions?